# Gitlab não exibe todas as alterações

Tags: git, gitlab

Num dos repositórios do GitLab acontece que em um commit foram adicionadas 93000 linhas.

Quando procuro por esse commit localmente, usando comandos como `git log`, `git show` por exemplo, tenho um retorno, através da flag `--stat`, de que realmente 93 mil linhas foram adicionadas.

Porém, quando vou olhar no GitLab ele não me exibe esse número.

Primeiro ele me exibe um número baixíssimo em relação a esse. Então, clicando na opção `Expand all` o número de adições aumenta consideravelmente embora não alcance o número esperado.

Mesmo assim ele me exibe mensagens como:

```
This diff is collapsed. Click to expand it.

This diff could not be displayed because it is too large.
```

- Qual o motivo do GitLab não me exibir o número de adições nesses
  casos?
- É algum problema na configuração? Se for, como posso resolver?

> A versão do GitLab é 8.11.2

Comment: Amigo dá uma olhada nessa issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

Dentre os arquivos de configuração do Gitlab há um com o nome "diff.rb", acredito que esteja em algum diretório dentro do "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/"

Vai ter dois parâmetros de "Limit" do Diff, algo como "DIFF_SIZE_LIMIT" e "DIFF_COLLAPSE_LIMIT" (ou algo assim), altere o valor deles para algo como 102400.

Espero ter ajudado.